# Excel VisualBasic Saving Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different Excel files named "A" and "C" started at the same time like two different programs.

So I want to make a macro in excel file "A" that saves excel file "C"
so literally instead clicking the save button in file "C"  to save file "C" i want to make a macro that saves file "C" from file "A" .

i hope you understand what is my problem

Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in the macro you could use the Workbook.Save method. Look this up in VBA help for more information on how to use.

A general starter example would be something like `MyWorkbook.Save`.

Comment: i think you missunderstood me , MyWorkbook.Save code will work to save the  Workbook working in excel file "A" but i wan't to save the workbook in excel file "C" via excel file "A" macro